# Flutter different alignments in a Row

Tags: flutter

[image: What I currently have]

[image: Desired Outcome]

How do I center one item in a row, while keeping another item in that same row aligned to start? I want the yellow arrow centered like in the picture. I have tried many things trying to get the third container to 'fill' the height so I can center it but I'm not having any luck. What can I do?

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      color: Colors.red,
      child: Icon(Icons.access_time, color: Colors.blue,),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      child: Icon(Icons.chevron_right, color: Colors.blue,),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `Row` inside a `SizedBox/Container` to give it a fixed height. Then wrap the `Containers` in `Align`. Like this for the first item

```
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Icon(
            Icons.access_time,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

And the second item:

```
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.yellow,
          child: Icon(
            Icons.chevron_right,
            color: Colors.blue,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: I don't know the height of the container ahead of time. its dictated by the height of the label which is dynamic based on the text thats in it

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by wrapping a row within a row

The first container is just in the original row, while containers 2 and 3 are in an Expanded(Row inside of the original Row